# Core Data cannot assign value of type optional to type entity

Tags: xcode, core-data

In my code below the variable number is increased by 10 every time when button is pressed. I want to overwrite number to the old one then save, fetch and display it on the View.
Unfortunately I get the following error message in  func fetchStats()
How can I assign a type of optional to a type entity?
Or easier to say: How can I overwrite the existing variable "number" with the old one, then save, fetch it with Core Data (to entity (Statsohs) with attribute (value)) and finally display it?

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var number : Double = 0
    
    //Reference to Managed Object Context
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    //Data for the Stats
    var average : Statsohs?

    @IBOutlet weak var LabelStats: UILabel!
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        fetchStats()
        
    }
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @IBAction func ActionButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        number = number + 10
        
        average = Statsohs(context: context)
        average?.value = number
        LabelStats.text = String(format: "%.2f", average!.value)
        
        //Save the data
                do {
                    try context.save()
                            
                }
                    catch {
                            
                }
        
    }
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    func fetchStats() {
        
            //Fetch the data from CoreData to display in the View
            do {
                average = try context.fetch(Statsohs.fetchRequest())
                   //Cannot assign value of type '[Statsohs]' to type 'Statsohs'
            }
            catch {
                
            }
        }
    
}
```

I tried different declarations of average in the beginning, e.g.:
average : [Statsohs]?
But then I will get the same error message in Action at average = Statsohs(conext: context)
And also member of type '[Statsohs]' has no member 'value'

I hope its possible in that way to assign value to Statsohs, save, fetch, display every time the updated value.

Comment: Dear @vadian: thank you for your qick reply including the explanations. Could you please show me how to adapt this to the code- with first and the overwrite part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetch` returns always an array of records (multiple items) even if there is only one.

To overwrite an attribute of a record you have to fetch the record, modify the attribute and save it back.

In `fetchStats` fetch the (single) record which is the first in the array. Assign it to `average` and its `value` to `number`. If it doesn't exist create one and assign zero to `value`

```
func fetchStats() {
        //Fetch the data from CoreData to display in the View
     do {
        if let found = try context.fetch(Statsohs.fetchRequest()).first {
            average = found
            number = found.value
        } else {    
            average = Statsohs(context: context)
            average?.value = 0
            saveData()
        }
        displayData()
            
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

In `actionButton` increment `number` by 10, assign the result to `value`, display and save the data

```
@IBAction func actionButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    number += 10.0
    average?.value = number
    saveData()
    displayData()
}
```

Finally add the helper methods `displayData` and `saveData`

```
func saveData() {
    do {
        try context.save()       
    } catch {
        print(error)              
    }

}

func displayData() {
    labelStats.text = String(format: "%.2f", number)
}
```

Comment: Dear @vadian: thank you so much for the corrected code. It works exactly I imagined.